# MySQLi Retrieve results for events in the next 12 months using CURDATE

Tags: mysql, sql

I am attempting to adjust code that I did not write in the first instance.

At the moment, the current code retrieves results for events in the next month and lists them. I need to make them display upcoming events for the next 12 months.

The current code looks like:

```
$current_events = $pdodb->prepare("
    SELECT * FROM events
    WHERE date_format(`start_date`, '%Y-%m') = date_format(now(), '%Y-%m') 
    AND end_date >= CURDATE() AND released = 'Y'"
);
```

I am thinking I need to adjust the **CURDATE()** to look something like **(CURDATE(), INTERVAL + 1 YEAR)**

But every thing I try just doesn't work, and I'm not having much luck reading tutes.

Comment: What constitutes an _"upcoming"_ event? How should the `start_date` and `end_date` be considered in your 12 month range?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that an *"upcoming"* event for date range *"the next 12 months*" is one that...

- Has a `start_date` between *"now"* and *"12 months from now"*, and
- Has an `end_date` between *"now"* and *"12 months from now"*

and assuming you have constraints ensuring `start_date` is **always** before `end_date`, try...

```
SELECT * FROM `events`
WHERE `released` = 'Y'
AND `start_date` BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH)
AND `end_date` BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH)
```

---

If the `end_date` doesn't matter, then simply omit the last clause. That will get you all the events starting in the next 12 months.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the logic `WHERE start_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH)`.
This will provide you with all the events that their start_date is from now to 12 months ahead.

Comment: You sure about that? Isn't this saying *"where `start_date` is on or after 12 months **ago**"*?